# How do i use the like operator in a case select for Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, case

I would like to write an SQL statement with a CASE WHEN clause that uses the LIKE operator but I am not sure how to properly format the statement.

```
 SELECT
   services.id,
   (CASE services.description
     WHEN LIKE '%-'
       THEN services.amount * -1
     ELSE services.amount
   END) AS service_amount
 FROM services
```

Comment: I know that storing the '-' in the description is not the ideal way of storing a negative number. I don't have the ability to update the code base or the database at this time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it on this way:

```
SELECT
   services.id,
   CASE WHEN services.description LIKE '%-'
        THEN services.amount * -1
        ELSE services.amount
   END) AS service_amount
 FROM services
```